# Range through times to pretty print by year

Tags: templates, go

Currently I'm printing post archive dates like so with https://play.golang.org/p/P1-sAo5Qy8:

- 2009 Nov 10»[Something happened in 2009](/foo/bar)
- 2005 Nov 10»[Something happened 10 years ago](/foo/old)
- 2009 Jun 10»[Summer of 2009](/foo/june)

Though I think it's nicer to print by year:

## 2009

- 2009 Nov 10»[Something happened in 2009](/foo/bar)
- 2009 Jun 10»[Summer of 2009](/foo/june)

## 2005

- 2005 Nov 10»[Something happened 10 years ago](/foo/old)

How would I range reverse chronically over the Posts PostDate, to print the grouping that I want? Can it be done all in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [sort.Interface](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) on your `Posts` struct, then sort it in reverse order.

```
type Posts struct {
    Posts []Post
}

func (p Posts) Len() int {
    return len(p.Posts)
}

func (p Posts) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return p.Posts[i].PostDate.Before(p.Posts[j].PostDate)
}

func (p Posts) Swap(i, j int) {
    p.Posts[i], p.Posts[j] = p.Posts[j], p.Posts[i]
}
```

and

```
posts := Posts{p}
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(posts))
```

That will give you the posts in the sequence you want them.

Next you'll have to implement a func using a closure so you can check if the current year is the same as the one for the last post to get the grouping by year. If yes output just the post, otherwise output a header with the year followed by the post.

```
currentYear := "1900"
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
    "newYear": func(t string) bool {
        if t == currentYear {
            return false
        } else {
            currentYear = t
            return true
        }
    },
}
```

and to use it:

```
{{ range . }}{{ if newYear (.PostDate.Format "2006") }}<li><h1>{{ .PostDate.Format "2006" }}</h1></li>{{ end }}
```

See a working example [on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vSfgOHUVTl).

Comment: Ah, that funcmap is genius!! Though ideally I would want the h1 to not be in the list item and the list items to be in a unordered list tag by year. e.g. `<h1>YYYY</h1><ul><li>post 1</li><li>post etc</li></ul>`.

Comment: That's pretty simple to accomplish at this point. Few small changes and here is a [new playground](https://play.golang.org/p/k4574UTyV2) sample. Biggest change is that you have to test for the first item so you don't stick a </ul> at the beginning. The sample produces exactly what you want.